# Unable to connect to local dynamo-db instance in java

Tags: java, docker, amazon-dynamodb, database-connection, dynamo-local

I am testing my application which uses dynamoDB. I have started an instance locally using docker and I'm able to create / add items in the instance.

Now, inside my Java application, I am trying to connect to my local and when I'm sending an API call that interacts with my local Dynamo, it throws an error -

> Unable to execute HTTP request: Unsupported or unrecognised SSL
> message

I've verified the endpoints and region using commands.
Java code snippet for connecting to dynamo -

```
AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder builder = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(amazonAWSCredentialsProvider());
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(endpoint))
        builder.withRegion(Regions.fromName(awsRegion));
    else
        builder.withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(endpoint, awsRegion));
    return builder.build();
```

I am not sure where this is failing. I am passing blank for access and secret key, region is the output of `aws configure get region`. Endpoint is configured to `localhost:8000`.

Stacktrace -

> 2021-10-26 17:44:35 [991c4652-5f7f-42ca-8aeb-447b385c535f] ERROR
> [http-nio-8085-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]
> [DirectJDKLog.java:175] Servlet.service() for servlet
> [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request
> processing failed; nested exception is
> com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request:
> Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message] with root cause
> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message
> at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:448)
> at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:184)
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:109)  at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1383)    at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1291)
> at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:435)
> at
> org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436)
> at
> org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
> at
> com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.connectSocket(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:142)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:76)

I am also unable to connect to `http://localhost:8000/shell` although my instance is running.

Comment: Is the Java application inside Docker or is the database inside Docker?

Comment: Java application is outside, running in a different port. Database is inside docker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working. I did not pay attention to the url I used, I should've used `http://localhost:8000` (with `http://`) instead of the pure `localhost:8000`.
Silly mistakes can eat a lot of your time!!